# How to keep LLDB running with redirected stdin, stdout and stderr

Tags: bash, macos, automation, lldb

I'm working on an automation task where I need to check whether some application is debuggable or not. So my workflow is:

- Attach LLDB to a process
- Set some breakpoints
- Perform some action in a target App
- Check a frame in LLDB for some expected expressions
- Detach debugger from App.

Since my test script has to switch between the App and the Debugger, I decided to have LLDB being run in a separate (background) process and interact with it through named pipes. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin
pipe=/tmp/mypipe
mkfifo $pipe    
lldb >out.txt 2>err.txt < $pipe &
```

I'm sending commands this way: `echo "attach -n AppName" > /tmp/mypipe`. But my problem is that after running any command, the LLDB exits. So the last lines in my out.txt are:

```
Executable module set to "/path/to/application".
Architecture set to: x86_64-apple-macosx.
```

And LLDB process is no longer exists. Is there any way to keep it running?
Thanks!